# Uninstalling Vibrancy from Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

To have a good look of vs code I have downloaded the extension called "Vibrancy".
It is really reallu buggy extension I have ever downloaded. Even after uninstalling, it keeps on showing its effect.
.
To delete it permanently (in windows)

- Close all tabs and windows.
- press win+R
- Type:- Temp and new screen pops up. Here delete all files.
- After this again press win+R.
- Type:- %temp%. And also delete all files.
- Also Restart vs code few times

Comment: what is the purpose of typing the post double, takes me longer to spot that it is a duplicate and I will not/never answer such a question, just like those SHOUT questions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Sorry, is this a question or a problem + solution? If it's a solution, don't put it in the question, post an answer instead (yes, you can [answer your own question](/help/self-answer)). And it wouldn't hurt to ask an actual question -- as simple as "How can I fully uninstall Vibrancy from Visual Studio Code?" For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: It's worth noting that the [Marketplace page for Vibrancy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eyhn.vscode-vibrancy) says *"The project is not actively maintained. To continue please move to [illixion/vscode-vibrancy-continued](https://github.com/illixion/vscode-vibrancy-continued)"*

Answer (score 0):

for removing the effect according to their github:
Press F1 and Activate command "Disable Vibrancy", and Restart Visual Studio Code. [See link](https://github.com/EYHN/vscode-vibrancy/blob/master/README.md#how-to-uninstall).

This is different from disabling the extencion itself.
for enabling again: Press F1 and Activate command "Reload Vibrancy".

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to uninstall normally, I was stuck with Vibrancy even after uninstalling the extension, as @omnidiw said, Press F1 (with your extension installed, if uninstalled, reinstall) then type `Disable Vibrancy` and press enter. It will ask you to restart the VSC, just do it and voila.
Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Press F1 (with your extension installed, if uninstalled, reinstall) then type Disable Vibrancy and press enter . it's not working for me . just uninstall this vibrancy extension . then uninstall vsc and install vsc again . just do it and enjoy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).